# Asus RT-AC66U_B1 Port forwarding not working only port 8443 is open?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, port-forwarding, port

i have an Asus RT-AC66U I just tried port forwarding port 9 and some other ports then I was going to https://portchecker.co/check to check if the ports where open witch there were not?? I also have remote web access enabled so port 8443 is open that is weird just I'm not running in double nat either I have Norton security antivirus but I have tried to disable that and the ports are still not open ??
[On This Image you can see that the port is closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y60Uc.png)

[Here you can see the ports that i have forwarded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoULz.png)

Comment: What service do you have that it listening on port 9?

Comment: teamviewer wake on lan with my public ddns